# RadGrid Custom Aggregate: where am I?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik-grid

I have a radgrid that needs multiple levels of grouping, with aggregates everywhere.  A few of these aggregates are custom ones, the first custom aggregates I've ever had to do.

I'm seeing that the OnCustomAggregate event fires for every custom aggregate: for each custom-aggregate column in any grouping in the hierarchy, and in the grid's "grand-total" footer.

My question: how can I tell, within my CustomAggregate event handler, WHAT group aggregate is being requested by the grid?  For instance, if my data is grouped by Country, then by State, how can I tell that the current call of CustomAggregate is for "Brazil", or "California", or "Grand Total for entire grid"?

My googling seems to be failing me today.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, I finally found a sample project that should get you started.  There is an entire sample project at this [link](http://www.telerik.com/forums/real-customaggregate-group-footer-example-needed), but I've attached the custom aggregate handling snippet below.

```
  protected void RadGrid1_CustomAggregate(object sender, GridCustomAggregateEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item is GridGroupFooterItem)
        {
            GridGroupFooterItem footer = e.Item as GridGroupFooterItem;
            GridItem[] groups = RadGrid1.MasterTableView.GetItems(GridItemType.GroupHeader);
            foreach (GridGroupHeaderItem group in groups)
            {
                if (group.GroupIndex == footer.GroupIndex)
                {
                    int count = 0;
                    e.Result = Calculate(group, count);
                }
            }
        }
        if (e.Item is GridFooterItem)
        {
            e.Result = 5;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That is quite helpful, thank you.

I don't see a great way, from the GroupHeaderItem or the GroupFooterItem, how to determine the group's selection criteria.  I'll limp along with parsing the group.DataCell.Text label, until I find something better.

Comment: Can you add your group info to the data keys on the individual items?  I assume once you've got the right group header you should be able to grab the first item inside the group easily enough...